# reading Local File on iPhone simulator crashes, but not on real device

Tags: iphone, file, ios-simulator

I'm developing an iphone App that download an `UTF8Encoded` file from a server, stores it in the Cache folder of the App and the simply copy its content to an `NSString* var`. It works on device but not on the simulator, here the code:

```
NSLog(@"File loaded into path: %@\n", localPath);
NSError* error;
NSString* tmpString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:localPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
//Prints the length in the console to check if the file has been correctly copied in the string
NSLog(@"tmpString length:%u", [tmpString length]);
```

On the simulator this portion of code prints:

```
File loaded into path: /Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/4FCF8FC6-4F1B-4FE5-92F6-A99EC8888E47/Library/Caches/utf8encodedFile.txt
```

But it crashes when it calls the "`stringWithContentsOfFile:`" method, displaying no errors

On the real device everything works well, it prints:

```
File loaded into path: /var/mobile/Applications/1EE8AEEB-D036-4ADE-AE12-836BA1F16BCB/Library/Caches/utf8encodedFile.txt
2012-06-30 19:19:24.743 appName[685:707] 
Error: (null)
2012-06-30 19:19:24.745 appName[685:707] tmpString length:1423
```

Comment: are you sure the file exists?

Comment: Sure, I've checked it both manually going to the Cache dir in the terminal and programmatically with the NsFileManager method to check if it exists. Clearing cache and uploading the file again didn't help. On the device it works flawlessly, but I don't like testing my app with my personal device :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading the contents of the file into an `NSData` and then create an `NSString` with it?

```
NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:
```

and `NSString`

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
```